# Group Action from to Subgroup to Group: Care in Differentiating Between Binary Op., Group Action Op.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, binary-operations

Using Dummit & Foote in a graduate level abstract algebra class, and it is my first introduction to group actions. I'm getting a better understanding as I go along, but one thing still puzzles me:

While I understand why care must be taken to differentiate between the inherent binary operation of the group and that of the group action (especially in terms of notation), for me it gets a little fuzzier when the group action is from a subgroup to the group in question. For example let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$. Define the group action $\phi$:$H\times G\to G$ by $(h,g)\mapsto h\cdot g$; i.e., left-multiplication on $G$ (I'm pulling this scenario from Dummit & Foote, too - and here they even call $\cdot$ left-multiplication).

So, at this point with my example, can there really be any difference between $\cdot$, the operation of the group action, and that of $G$? Certainly $h\cdot g \in G$, and of course $hg\in G$ by closure (using concatenation to denote the binary operation of $G$). Since D&F called $\cdot$ left-multiplication, is it not true that $h\cdot g =hg$? What about in the general case, i.e. any group action from a subgroup to a group? Is the group action operation the same as the binary operation of the group?

Comment: Basically you are right, although I would put it a bit more precisely: the group action operation is the same as **the restriction of** the binary operation $G \times G \to G$ to the subset $H \times G \subset G \times G$, thus obtaining a function $H \times G \to G$.

Comment: I'm posting this here, since I think it's related, instead of starting a new thread.  I've been studying group actions.  So far, the only examples of group actions that I've seen are (left or right) multiplication G x X: (g,x) -> g * x or x * g, and conjugation G x X: (g,x) -> g * x * g^(-1).  Are there other possibilities for a group action?

Comment: "discrete" group actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different since $H\times G$ for $H<G$ is not $G\times G$.

Moreover, the use of $\cdot$ is a little like the definition

$$\begin{align} 
+:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R & \to \Bbb R,\\
(r,s) &\mapsto r+s
\end{align}$$

compared to

$$\begin{align}
+\rvert_{\Bbb Z}:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb R&\to \Bbb R,\\
(r,s)&\mapsto r+s.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great example, thank you. So, the operation might be the same so to speak, but depending on the subset, the output could be different, hence care should be taken to still note a difference between the group action op. and the binary op.

Comment: You're welcome, @greycatbird; and you're right.